# Is there still a need for 3rd party SEO extensions with the new Joomla 2.5?

Tags: seo, joomla

In Joomla 2.5 they upgraded the core SEO.

That got me to thinking, do I still need to use third party extensions for my SEO? If yes, why? What is it that 3rd party extensions provide that Joomla 2.5's built-in SEO doesn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The biggest reason why using an SEO component in all versions of Joomla even 3+ is that Joomla has a habit of creating multiple urls for one page/post meaning that Google finds these as duplicates.

There are just so many reasons why using a SEO extensions for Joomla is better than using the core but here's a few:

- Better REL="Canonical" Support
- Better at handling friendly urls with scanning for duplicate pages
- Scans Meta/Title for Duplicates
- Handles redirects a 100x better than core
- Easier to manage the meta data within one page (see all when viewing all)
- Easier add Google plus and other social networking attributes to the head.
- The list goes on and on.

I suggest you check out two of the most popular extensions for Joomla: [AceSEF](http://www.joomace.net/joomla-extensions/acesef-joomla-seo-sef-urls) and [SH404SEF](http://anything-digital.com/sh404sef/seo-analytics-and-security-for-joomla.html)

I've personally used both and SH404SEF offers the most to be honest but AceSEF has a free version and does the job just fine.

Answer (score -2):

I second SH404SEF.

More than 100 sites with that, some huge (+20k items), with K2 and other extensions (evem custom ones), and all the issues that we had were easily dealt with.

Comment: @Jonathon Roza Your reply should be a comment not an answer. Thanks for the response though. I've just started using sh404SEF, it seems quite good.

Comment: New to stack exchange (as an active, kinda productive, member :-) You'll find some bumps on the road, as no software is 100%, and some things are a lot of work to make it work perfectly, but at least you have the ability to achieve what you need. So, hard to master tool, well worth it.